# Geometrical Inequalities

Tags: inequality, geometric-inequalities

I couldnt solve the following: we need to minimize $$\sqrt{\frac{(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(a+c-b)}{(a+b+c)}},$$ where a,b,c are sides of a triangle.

Comment: In the extreme case where $a+b \approx c$, the above term is close to zero.

Comment: Just curious where this problem came from.  Is it related to Heron's formula in some way?

Comment: I dont know where it comes from,I was asked by my brother

Comment: @Mike Yes, it is. And very related to the inradius ;)

Answer (score 2):

This expression can be arbitrarily close to $0$. Let $a=2\varepsilon$, $b = c = 1/2 - \varepsilon$. There is a triangle with sides $a$, $b$, and $c$. As $\varepsilon$ goes to $0$, the expression approaches $0$. Specifically, we have
$$\sqrt{\frac{(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(a+c-b)}{(a+b+c)}} 
= \sqrt{\frac{2\varepsilon \cdot (1 - 4\varepsilon)\cdot 2\varepsilon}{1}} \leq \sqrt{2\varepsilon \cdot 2\varepsilon} = 2\varepsilon.$$
This expression can be arbitrarily close to $0$.

The expression is *maximized* when $a=b=c$.

Comment: can you show it in a classical way, I need it for high school 1st year students?

Comment: OK, I'll do that.

Comment: what if a+b+c is fixed some p.

Comment: again it would be when a=b=c,but this way wouldnt work

Comment: just multiply all parameters $a$, $b$, $c$ and $\varepsilon$ by $p$

Answer (score 0):

Also, by Heron's formula the expression in question is Area/4 Perimeter. So of course it can be arbitrary close to zero. (Note that the maximal area given fixed perimeter is for the equilateral triangle, as can be shown geometrically rather easily).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this expression can get arbitrarily close to zero.

By multiplying both the numerator and the denominator of the fraction by (a+b+c) and simplifying and plugging in A=rs (r is in-radius s is semi-perimeter) we have our eexpression is equivalent to

$$ 2r$$
Therefore it can get arbitrarily small.